# Transition of Vedas to Puranas and Tantric literature

Tags: vedas, puranas, itihasa

How and why did the people transition from the Vedic literature to the Puranic and Tantric. If Vedas are fundamental with its essence cumulated into the Upanishads, why and how did it transition into Puranic and temple culture. **What was the need?** What did the Vedas lack that lead to Puranas to take precedence? Its easy to say "they are the same" and that they a different flavor, which is not true. Cherry picking few stories does'nt explain its evolution. I say evolution, because it didn't happen in a day, it would have taken few centuries. Neither Buddha nor Adi Shankara use Puranas as their basis. Buddha never referred to either the puranas nor the itihasa.

Comment: Tantra was not a transition. Vedic culture and Tantric both co-existed since the start. Refer PKS.

Comment: Why was the question Down voted? Which part of the question seem negative or false?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto may be Tantra and Vedic sects did co-exist. But people still choose to move away from Vedic and into Tantra. Or those following Tantra continued allowing many to become its part. Which is still a transition. Unless Vedic people just got up and disappeared. So a level of transition did happen more into the Puranic and Agamic culture.

Comment: Vedic paths are slower, tantric paths are faster, but they often come with a cost - safety. There are traditions - Kashmir Shivaism and so on where Vedas weren't taken as authority. But they were much faster in comparison to regular vedic path.